# Looking for a more elegant way to assign a "selected" attribute to a previously chosen <input> element

Tags: php, dropdown, html-select, crud

I'm creating a simple CRUD app with PHP. On the create page, there's a dropdown menu that allows the user to select what type of highway they're entering info for.  On the update page, I'd like the choice that the user made on the create page to be preserved.  The value the user chose has been stored in the local JSON object.  I came up with the following solution:

```
<select name="route-type" id="route-type" required>

<option value="" selected="true" disabled>What type of route is this?</option>

<?php if( $highway['type'] == 'interstate') { ?>

<option value="interstate" selected>Interstate</option>
<option value="us-route">US Route</option>
<option value="state-route">State Route</option>

<?php } elseif ( $highway['type'] == 'us-route') { ?>
                
<option value="interstate">Interstate</option>
<option value="us-route" selected>US Route</option>
<option value="state-route">State Route</option>

<?php } elseif ( $highway['type'] == 'state-route') { ?>

<option value="interstate">Interstate</option>
<option value="us-route">US Route</option>
<option value="state-route" selected>State Route</option>

<?php } ?>
```

The problem is this seems pretty repetitive and begs to be refactored or rewritten somehow.  Any suggestions?  Obviously if there were 30 choices in the dropdown it wouldn't be correct to have 30 possible outcomes in the if statement.

Comment: I do not know why you were down voted.   I do have a question.  Where did you learn to use that switching back and forth between PHP mode and HTML mode?  Personalty I go with there should only be one `<?php` at the top of the php file and one `?>` at the bottom.  I find your code too time consuming to read due to the unnecessary and constant `<?php` and `?>` switching.

Comment: @Misunderstood I agree, sometimes it feels like a lot of extra typing.  When I first started learning PHP one of the ways we were taught to write it was to "wrap" it around the HTML.  It makes the HTML easier to parse for some people (maybe?) but there's more to keep track of for sure as opposed to just writing out "echo" for the HTML lines.

Comment: That was the WordPress did (does) it.  I call it the WordPress PHP style.   Do you ever use the HERDOC echo?  I put the HTML between `echo <<<EOT` and `EOT;` And you just type in variables wherever they are needed.  PHP stands for "Personal Home Page"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's a solution (untested):

```php
$options = [
  'interstate' => 'Interstate',
  'use-route' => 'US Route',
  'state-route' => 'State Route'
];

foreach($options as $k=>$v) {
  echo "<option value=\"$k\"" . ($k===$highway['type']?'selected':'') . " />$v</option>\n";
}
```